# How can I limit the maximum width/height of a column in AmCharts 4 XYChart

Tags: typescript, amcharts4

Is it possible to limit the maximum width of a column in an XY Chart?
I am using AmCharts4 in an Angular Project with Typescript.

In the picture below:

- Left Chart: What happens when I send many rows of data to an XY Chart
- Middle Chart: When I send one row of data to an XY Chart.
- Right Chart: What I would like to have happen when I send one row of data to an XY Chart

Is there a way to prevent the 2nd chart from having its single column expand so much? It's fine if it expands, but I would like to be able to limit it in some way.

Maybe something like?
`categoryAxis.maxColumnWidth = 50`

I checked the documentation here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/managing-width-and-spacing-of-column-series/ but did not see anything.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the maxWidth of Column Series like this:

```
let columnSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries()); 
columnSeries.columns.template.maxWidth = 50
```

Comment: In my case, I actually needed to use `columnSeries.columns.template.maxHeight = 50`, but this was exactly what I needed. Thank you! The documentation for the column template is here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/roundedrectangle/